# UITableView edit forces checkboxes on iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

I've got a `UITableView` which lets users select filters for a search function: tap on each row to add applicable filters, etc.  When a row is selected, the app does a bunch of things, including adding a custom icon to the far right of the row to indicate that it has been selected.

On iOS 7 everything worked fine, but now on iOS 8 it is forcing checkmarks on the far left of each selected row, (much like when you select multiple emails to edit in Mail).

This seems like it's probably a simple fix, just a new property or something to set in iOS 8, but I can't find anything along those lines.  I'd post some code, but I don't know what in the code is making this happen (or failing to stop it from happening) in iOS 8.

Can anyone help me hide those "edit checkmarks" in a `UITableView`, or explain why they would be behaving differently in iOS 8?

**UPDATE:** Below is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, as requested in the comments.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HierarchyLookupBase* item = [_Hierachy itemForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    KFTableViewCellHierarchyStyle* cell = (KFTableViewCellHierarchyStyle *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[KFTableViewCellHierarchyStyle alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        [self selectedCellView:cell];
    }

    cell.indentationLevel = [_Hierachy levelForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.text = item.Description;
    cell.isLastChild = item.isLastChild;
    cell.hasSelectedChildren = item.hasSelectedChildren;
    if (item.isSelected) {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The `selectRowAtIndexPath` method is currently untouched.

Comment: It's your code that's creating the checkmarks. They are not appearing by magic. So if you want help with that code, show what it is.

Comment: As I said in the original post, I don't know what's causing it.  I'm looking for someone to help me locate what tells the TableView to create checkboxes when it goes into Edit mode.  I'm working with code written by someone else, but given that the different iOS versions act differently, I'm thinking it's a built-in behavior of the TableView.  For example, some tables make Delete buttons or allow users to reorder rows when editing, but this one (and many others) allow them to check multiple rows.  Where do you set that Edit behavior?

Comment: Post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: @rmaddy Added method.

Comment: Your call to `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` must not be done in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Now add your `selectedCellView:` method to your question.

Comment: Ok, here's a weird thing: the `selectedCellView:` method was commented out. (Like I said, I'm working my way through someone else's code at a new job.) But when I comment out the `selectedCellView:` line in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, the behavior changes (the background color of the row becomes blue when it was white). I've traced up through the inheritance chain, and none of them have custom `selectedCellView:` methods. How could a call to a commented-out method be different than no call at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

does trigger that checkmark. You probably have to override that too.

Answer (score -1):

Try set `self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;`

This property is settable in `IB` as well.